# Padding in background

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I created this small example code in order to represent the problem that I face:

```
package test.barimages;

import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application
{
    ObjectProperty<Label> selectedText = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        selectedText.addListener((obs, oldSelectedText, newSelectedText) ->
        {
            if (oldSelectedText != null)
            {
                oldSelectedText.setStyle("");
            }
            if (newSelectedText != null)
            {
                newSelectedText.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightgray; -fx-padding: 5;");
            }
        });

        FlowPane navigationBar = new FlowPane();
        navigationBar.setMaxHeight(45);
        navigationBar.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        navigationBar.setVgap(10);   // Set vertical gap size
        navigationBar.setHgap(10);

        Label FirstIcon = FirstIcon();
        Label SecIcon = SecIcon();
        Label ThurIcon = ThurIcon();

        selectedText.set(FirstIcon);

        navigationBar.getChildren().addAll(FirstIcon, SecIcon, ThurIcon);

        Scene scene = new Scene(navigationBar);

        stage.setTitle("JavaFX and Maven");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    private Label FirstIcon()
    {
        Image image = new Image("http://goo.gl/kYEQl");
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        imageView.setImage(image);

        Label label = new Label("First");
        label.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 12));
        label.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.LEFT);

        label.setGraphicTextGap(8);

        imageView.setFitWidth(40);
        imageView.setFitHeight(40);
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
        imageView.setSmooth(true);
        imageView.setCache(true);

        label.setGraphic(imageView);

        label.setOnMouseClicked((event) ->
        {
            selectedText.set(label);
        });

        return label;
    }

    private Label SecIcon()
    {
        Image image = new Image("http://goo.gl/kYEQl");
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        imageView.setImage(image);

        Label label = new Label("Second");
        label.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 12));
        label.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.LEFT);

        label.setGraphicTextGap(8);

        imageView.setFitWidth(40);
        imageView.setFitHeight(40);
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
        imageView.setSmooth(true);
        imageView.setCache(true);

        label.setGraphic(imageView);

        label.setOnMouseClicked((event) ->
        {
            selectedText.set(label);
        });

        return label;
    }

    private Label ThurIcon()
    {
        Image image = new Image("http://goo.gl/kYEQl");
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        imageView.setImage(image);

        Label label = new Label("Thurd");
        label.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 12));
        label.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.LEFT);

        label.setGraphicTextGap(8);

        imageView.setFitWidth(40);
        imageView.setFitHeight(40);
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
        imageView.setSmooth(true);
        imageView.setCache(true);

        label.setGraphic(imageView);

        label.setOnMouseClicked((event) ->
        {
            selectedText.set(label);
        });

        return label;
    }
}
```

When you run the code and you click over the images you will see that selected Label pushes the next one. This is caused by the padding. Is there any way to preserve the background adding without pushing the near images?

Comment: You want to add padding without changing the layout bounds? Isn't that an oxymoron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't make anything from the question, so my *guess* from your example is that you don't want the selection to be cut off at the image/text.

First: having padding without occupying space is a contradiction.

You have to approach the matter differently: You change the attributes of the FlowPane. You can easily drop the hgap/vgap of the flowpane and instead add padding to each clickable node.

Example change:

```
selectedText.addListener((obs, oldSelectedText, newSelectedText) ->
{
    if (newSelectedText != null)
    {
        newSelectedText.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightgray");

    }
});

FlowPane navigationBar = new FlowPane();
navigationBar.setMaxHeight(45);
navigationBar.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
navigationBar.setVgap(10);   
navigationBar.setHgap(0); // set to 0, instead add padding to every node

Label FirstIcon = FirstIcon();
FirstIcon.setPadding(new Insets( 5)); // add padding
Label SecIcon = SecIcon();
SecIcon.setPadding(new Insets( 5)); // add padding
Label ThurIcon = ThurIcon();
ThurIcon.setPadding(new Insets( 5)); // add padding
```

Something like that. It gives you space around the Node while keeping the space of the overall layout the way you had it. I have no information what you really want to achieve. So you have to toy around with the inset values if some pixels aren't the way you want them.

Comment: Yes, this is the exact solution. By the way is there more simple solution?

Comment: You could create a CSS file with styles for a selected and an unselected state. The style of course includes the padding.

Comment: I mean instead of using padding for every icon background is there a way to make the same visual result with less code?

Comment: Yes, as I said, apply a style to the label. Or you could create a custom label which has the style applied in its constructor.